# R Sorting Matrix name, including 1 string but excluding the other

Tags: r, sorting

I am currently trying to sort a matrix, and for the life of me can't figure out how to do this. I have rownames that consist of 2 words, and I want to be able to compare them by sorting these 2 words. Currently I am able to use grep to sort for the 2 words that I want. Here is a quick example.

```
x <- matrix(NA,nrow=12,ncol=2)
multi <- 4
colour <- c("Red","Blue","Dark Blue")
colour <- as.vector(sapply(colour,function(y) rep(y,multi)))
food <- c("Water","Milk","Juice")
food <- as.vector(t(sapply(food,function(y) rep(y,multi))))
rownames(x) <- paste(food,colour,sep=" ,")

Milk <- x[grep(paste0("^Milk ,","Blue$"),rownames(x)),]
```

What I am trying to do now from the above example, is find a way to sort for everything except "Milk", but still have the colour "Blue". Any ideas?

This is the current output

```
            [,1] [,2]
Milk ,Blue   NA   NA
Milk ,Blue   NA   NA
```

What I would like is this. It would need to be able to differentiate between "Blue" and "Dark Blue".

```
       [,1] [,2]
Water ,Blue   NA   NA
Juice ,Blue   NA   NA
```

Comment: Use the logical version of grep and remove every row which contains "Milk" `x[ !grepl("Milk",rownames(x)),]`

Comment: Are you aware that `rep` has an `each`-argument, allowing you to do `rep(colour, each=4)` instead of `as.vector(sapply......`

Comment: This is a quick mock up, I didn't really care how I put the example together, I just wanted something to use as an example. But thank you for letting me know!

Comment: @MikeJewski are your real data exactly like this `word ,word` (I mean separated by a single space and a coma) or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a negative lookbehind to specify instances of `Blue` that do not proceed `Milk`:

```
x[grep("(?<!Milk ),Blue", row.names(x), perl = TRUE),]
            [,1] [,2]
Juice ,Blue   NA   NA
Water ,Blue   NA   NA
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! I have one more question, but I will accept this as the answer either way. Is there a way to specify strictly only "Blue"? My colours might be "Dark Blue", as well as "Blue". can grep specify between these two?

Comment: What do you mean with differentiate between "Blue" and "Dark Blue". As the pattern "Blue" occures also in "Dark Blue" it is also detected.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to specify strictly "Blue" or strictly "Dark Blue". I can find a way around it, I am just curious

Comment: Can you use "Dark Blue" as pattern?

Comment: Dark Blue as a pattern works, but it is when I use Blue as a pattern that it also picks up all of the words associated with Dark Blue

Comment: Just move the coma out of the negative lookbehind, you'll match ',Blue' so not ',Dark Blue', I.e: use the coma as part of the match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logical version and run it twice, or you can split your data (first you have to transform it into a data.frame).,

```
# Create the data, including rownames with Dark Blue

x <- matrix(NA,nrow=12,ncol=2)
colour <- rep(c("Red" ,"Blue", "Green", "Dark Blue"), 3)
food <- rep(c("Water ","Milk", "Juice"), 4)
rownames(x) <- paste(food, colour, sep=" ,")

# only Blue
x[ !grepl("Milk|Dark Blue", rownames(x)) & grepl("Blue", rownames(x)), ]
# only Dark Blue
x[ !grepl("Milk", rownames(x)) & grepl("Dark Blue", rownames(x)), ]

# or use split to create a list (Now with the solution from Pierre Lafortune)
x1 <- x[grep("(?<!Milk ,)Blue", rownames(x), perl = TRUE),]
gr <- ifelse(grepl("Dark Blue", rownames(x1)), 1, 2) # factor 1== Dark Blue; 2==Blue
split(data.frame(x1), gr)
```

Comment: Using two regex is overkill